# backward and forward recurrence times

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process, renewal-processes

I am trying to find the following probability in a renewal poisson process: $P[Y(t)>x/A(t+ \frac{x}{2})=s] $, where $A(t)=t-S_{N(t)}$ and $Y(t)=S_{N(t)+1}-t$.

I assumed that $X_{N(t)+1}=A(t+ \frac{x}{2}) +Y(t)- \frac{x}{2}=s- \frac{x}{2}+Y(t)>s- \frac{x}{2} +x=s+ \frac{x}{2}$.

Thus,  $P[Y(t)>x/A(t+ \frac{x}{2})=s] =\frac{P[Y(t)>x,A(t+ \frac{x}{2})=s] }{P(A(t+ \frac{x}{2})=s)}=\frac{P(X_{N(t)+1}>s+\frac{x}{2})}{P(A(t+ \frac{x}{2})=s)}=\frac{\overline{F}(\frac{x}{2} +s)}{P(A(t+ \frac{x}{2})=s)}$,

and $\overline{F}(s)=1-F(s)$.

I do not know if all that are correct, but if they are I do not know how to deal  with $P(A(t+ \frac{x}{2})=s)$ .

Is there any concrete relation with $A(t), Y(t)$ and the distribution function $F(t)$?

Comment: By $\mathbb P(Y(t)>x/A(t+\frac x2)=s)$ do you mean the probability of $\{Y(t)>x\}$ conditioned on $\{A(t+\frac x2)=s\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Both the backward and forward recurrence times are exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$, and are independent due to the memoryless property. Therefore $\mathbb P(Y(t)>x\mid A(t)=s)=\mathbb P(Y(t)>x)$. However, if $N\left(t+\frac x2\right)>N(t)$, then the conditional probability $\mathbb P\left(Y(t)>x\mid A\left(t+\frac x2\right)=s\right)$ is zero. It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left(Y(t)>x\mid A\left(t+\frac x2\right)=s\right) &= \mathbb P\left(Y(t)>x\mid A\left(t\right)=s\right)\mathbb P\left(N\left(t+\frac x2\right) - N(t) = 0\right)\\
&= \mathbb P(Y(t>x)\mathbb P\left(N\left(\frac x2\right)=0\right)\\
&= \left(\int_x^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda u}\ \mathsf du\right)\cdot e^{-\lambda\frac x2}\\
&= e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\lambda\frac x2}\\
&= e^{-\lambda\left(x+\frac x2\right)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I cannot understand the first equivalence. Is it true that $P(A(t)< x)=e^{- \lambda x}$?

Comment: @jane No, instead we have $\mathbb P(A(t)>x) = e^{-\lambda x}$.